# Can I wrap a table vertically?

Tags: html, html-table, word-wrap

I have a table that is much taller than it is wide.

I want to know if it's possible to make the table wrap vertically so that instead of scrolling to see the data, the table 'wraps' to the unused portion of the page.

This is the basic format I want

```
01   05   09
02   06   10
03   07   11
04   08   12
```

My thought is that I could manage it all via javascript but before I do things the hard way, what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: It'll likely take some serious javascript to accomplish this behavior. You might look into one of the jQuery table suites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this..

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H7pKB/)**

[image]

---

### Notes:

- Table must have `<thead>` and `<tbody>`
- Probably breaks under many conditions (`colspan`, `rowspan`, empty cells)
- Some styling dependent on CSS3
- Code is not streamlined

Comment: +2 awesome points.Very, very nice.  I went a lazier route for the mock-up but this does exactly what I need and as I move towards production I'll incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean but I'm assuming that you want the table's to have more or less columns depending on the height of the available page space.

If this is the case I'd suggest using an unordered list and changing the width of the UL.

I assume you might need to have some core function which calculates the number of rows that can fit into the page height. If all the LI s are the same you can do this by getting the height of one of them and then overall height of the page or space you have available.

To reorder the LI s if you need this James Padolsey has create a great jquery plug in.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Multi-column Layout Module** can accomplish this easily but is not supported in all browsers, only Firefox and Webkit so far.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

http://html5.litten.com/css3-series-multiple-columns/

I'm not aware of any drop-in JavaScript compatibility tools for this functionality, yet.

Comment: The perfect solution, but might be a problem due to browser compatability.  It's the very essence of web programming.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's not possible to break a table accross columns.  The list solution will work, but my experiments with FF 3.6 have not yet demonstrated that a table can be wrapped in this way.